# Pass JSON OnClick ASP.NET Button

Tags: asp.net, json, event-handling

How can I pass my JSON with asp.net button control's `OnClick` event to its event handler? Because `OnClick` will be set to an event handler. I don't see a way to send data as argument. I have figured out an alternative with `jQuery.Ajax` but I would still like to know how to do it orwhether its possible or viable.

Answer (score 1):

You could send it as a normal POST value, lets say a HiddenField.

**Steps:**

- Define a HiddenField on the page.
- Fill it with the JSON value on the client side before posting back.
- On the button event handler, grab the HiddenField's value, which would be the JSON.
- Parse the Value and do what you have to do.

Another way would be to implement the `IPostBackEventHandler` interface on your control/page and do the postback directly to them instead of using the buttons postback. In this case you could pass the JSON value directly on the call to the ASP.NET `__doPostBack` javascript function.